# Python Modules on commandline

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I just found out about the following code I can enter into the command line:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Where can I find more documentation about the modules and what I can do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [main Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/), there is [a note at the bottom of the `SimpleHTTPServer` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html). Other modules such as [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) and [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) have similar notes.

Answer (score 1):

The overall `-m` command line feature is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-m) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module).  You can use it for you own modules. As noted, for individual standard lib modules it's best to consult their source code.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly in the source itself. There is almost no documentation on which can be used this way, and not all of them do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Or in Python 3:

```
python -m http.server
```